# Move chart x axis label and borders

Tags: chart.js

I have the following code and am trying to achieve 2 things.

1. I need to hide the main borders of the graph - I've looked up the Gridlines configuration within ChartJS and also examples here in Stack and for some reason my borders remain??

As you'll see from the fiddle, I have used:

`"gridlines": { "display": false, "drawBorder": false, "drawTicks": false}`

But to no avail

2. I need to move the dates above the graph not keep them below it. There doesn't seem to be a simple way to do this unless I get into the animation function and start calculating x/y positions. Is there an easier way??

Here is my basic line graph JSfiddle and the settings I've used https://jsfiddle.net/qogx7epL/

Comment: Can I just add that the reason my code wasn't working as well was because I had `gridlines` not `gridLines` which the answer also helped point out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your config object like that to remove plot borders:
https://jsfiddle.net/3ko21xaq/

```
...
options: {
    ...
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                drawTicks: false,
                display: false
            },
            ...
        }],
        xAxes: [{
            gridLines: {
                drawTicks: false,
                display: false
            },
            ...
        }]
    },
},
```

To set x-axis to the top may do the trick this options: https://jsfiddle.net/d3s7x2af/

```
xAxes: [{
    ticks: {
        display: true,
        position: "top", // Not found in documentation((
        mirror: true,
        padding: -400, // Set the height of the plot
    },
}]
```

More about ticks configuration -> https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/#tick-configuration

Comment: Thats great. Unfortunately I cannot award this as the answer because it was a 2 part question - the other part is about moving the x tick values to the top of the graph. But thanks for the answer thus far.

Comment: @Antony Updated the answer. May be it's not the best solution but it seems to be working)

Comment: The labels are half hidden though?

Comment: @Antony 
If you plots won't be resizable you can tune padding value once and forget about it))) 
Otherwise it won't work cuz padding has fixed value(((
I don't know how to dynamically change it.
Try to resize plot window here and you'll see -> https://jsfiddle.net/weLjaqs1/